# Key being repeated on the firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting repeated "keys" from Firebase, I did not find anything referring to the documentation. Who has experience in the subject could pass the knowledge of why this happens and how to circumvent this "error"?

I just created a function to get all the shopping malls that the company contains, after that go through each of these shopping malls to get their lat lng. But the "Barra Shopping" is being repeated.

[image: PICTURE]

[image: CONSOLE]

**CODE:**

```
function searchAllMarkers(){
    var markers = firebase.database().ref('/').child('aliansce');
    var arrMarkers = [];

    markers.on('child_added', function(snap){
        arrMarkers = [...arrMarkers, snap.key];
        console.log(arrMarkers);

        for(m in arrMarkers){
            console.log(arrMarkers[m])
            var markers = firebase.database().ref('/aliansce/').child('' + arrMarkers[m] +'/marker/markerCoordinates/');
            markers.on('child_added', function(snap){
                console.log(snap.val());
            });

        }

    });  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `child_added` callback is invoked separately for each child node, so once for `barrashopping` and once for `viapark`.

Each time it gets invoked, you add the node to an array, and then log the array with `console.log(arrMarkers[m])`.

1. The first time `child_added` fires for `barrashopping`, your array contains `[barrashopping]` and you log `barrashopping`.
2. The second time 'child_added`fires it's for`viapark`, so you array now contains`[barrashopping, viapark]`and you log`barrashopping, viapark`.

The more nodes you have, the more frequently you will print `barrashopping` with your current code. One way to prevent this is to listen to the `value` event, which one fires once for all children matching your query:

```
function searchAllMarkers(){
    var markers = firebase.database().ref('/').child('aliansce');
    var arrMarkers = [];

    markers.once('value', function(parent){
      parent.forEach(function(snap) {
        arrMarkers = [...arrMarkers, snap.key];

        for(m in arrMarkers){
            var markers = firebase.database().ref('/aliansce/').child('' + arrMarkers[m] +'/marker/markerCoordinates/');
            markers.once('child_added', function(snap){
                console.log(snap.val());
            });
        }

        console.log(arrMarkers);
      }
    });  
}
```

Comment: I had already tried it, but it still repeats the same "key" and "val ()" of this key.

Comment: Yeah, the logging was still in the wrong place. Fixed it now. But I also recommend that you put a breakpoint in the code and step through it once or twice to see how it flows and what you're printing. It's a lot easier to understand what's happening in a debugger, than by having someone talk you through it here.